# How to test for uniqueness of value in Yup.array?

Tags: javascript, validation, formik, yup

I have form with dynamic amount of inputs (admin email) however checking for uniqueness fails:

```
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        adminEmails: Yup.array()
          .of(
            Yup.string()
              .notOneOf(Yup.ref('adminEmails'), 'E-mail is already used')
```

What is best approach here? 
FYI, as a form helper I use `Formik`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
Yup.addMethod(Yup.array, 'unique', function(message, mapper = a => a) {
    return this.test('unique', message, function(list) {
        return list.length  === new Set(list.map(mapper)).size;
    });
});
```

Then use it like this:

```
const headersSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    adminEmails: Yup.array().of(
        Yup.string()
    )
    .unique('email must be unique')
})
```

Comment: This works, but unable to add error to the duplicate input. Any way to add error to duplicate inputs?
structure: `users: [{name: 'one user', age: 23}, {name: 'two user', age: 28}]`. Want to add error to duplicate names.

Answer (score 7):

This is a simple inline solution to validate that an array of strings only contains unique elements:

```
Yup.array().of(Yup.string())
.test(
  'unique',
  'Only unique values allowed.',
  (value) => value ? value.length === new Set(value)?.size : true
)
```

Comment: Was running into issues when trying to use the `.unique` method with typescript using the `addMethod` call above. This is the much simpler solution and workd first time 

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have the errors in each field and not in the array

```
Yup.addMethod(Yup.mixed, 'uniqueIn', function (array = [], message) {
    return this.test('uniqueIn', message, function (value) {
        return array.filter(item => item === value).length < 2;
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer runs `array.filter` for each row. See my answer below for a version that runs it only once per call to validate.

Answer (score 3):

Simply Do This It works for me

First Define this function in your react component

```
    Yup.addMethod(Yup.array, "unique", function (message, mapper = (a) => a) {
    return this.test("unique", message, function (list) {
      return list.length === new Set(list.map(mapper)).size
    })
  })
```

Just Put this schema inside your **Formik** tag

```
<Formik
    initialValues={{
      hotelName: "",
      hotelEmail: [""],
    }}
    validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
      hotelName: Yup.string().required("Please enter hotel name"),
      hotelEmail: Yup.array()
        .of(
          Yup.object().shape({
            email: Yup.string()
              .email("Invalid email")
              .required("Please enter email"),
          }),
        )
        .unique("duplicate email", (a) => a.email),
    })}
    onSubmit={(values, { validate }) => {
      getFormPostData(values)
    }}
    render={({ values, errors, touched }) => (
      <Form>
            <FieldArray
                  name="hotelEmail"
                  render={(arrayHelpers) => (
                    <>
                      {values.hotelEmail.map((hotel, index) => (
                        <div class="row" key={index}>
                          <div className="col-md-8 mt-3">
                            <div className="user-title-info user-details">
                              <div className="form-group d-flex align-items-center mb-md-4 mb-3">
                                <label className="mb-0" htmlFor="hotelName">
                                  {lang("Hotelmanagement.hotelsystemadmin")}
                                  <sup className="text-danger">*</sup>
                                </label>
                                <div className="w-100">
                                  <Field
                                    name={`hotelEmail.${index}.email`}
                                    className="form-control"
                                    id="hotelEmail"
                                    placeholder={lang(
                                      "Hotelmanagement.hotelsystemadmin",
                                    )}
                                  />
                                  <span className="text-danger d-block">
                                    {errors &&
                                      errors.hotelEmail &&
                                      errors.hotelEmail[index] &&
                                      errors.hotelEmail[index].email && (
                                        <span className="text-danger d-block">
                                          {errors.hotelEmail[index].email}
                                        </span>
                                      )}
                                      {errors &&
                                      errors.hotelEmail &&(
                                        <span className="text-danger d-block">
                                          {errors.hotelEmail}
                                        </span>
                                      )}
                                  </span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="col-md-2 mt-3">
                            {index > 0 && (
                              <i
                                className="bx bx-minus addnewBtn "
                                onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}
                              />
                            )}
                            {index === values.hotelEmail.length - 1 && (
                              <i
                                className="bx bx-plus addnewBtn ml-5"
                                onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push("")}
                              />
                            )}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </>
                  )}
                />
```

not to show error do this following

```
 {errors &&
   errors.hotelEmail &&(
      <span className="text-danger d-block">
            {errors.hotelEmail}
      </span>
 )}
```

)}
      />

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late to respond, but anyways, you should use `this.createError({path, message});`

See example:

```html
yup.addMethod(yup.array, 'growing', function(message) {
    return this.test('growing', message, function(values) {
        const len = values.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i === 0) continue;
            if (values[i - 1].intervalTime > values[i].intervalTime) return this.createError({
                path: `intervals[${i}].intervalTime`,
                message: 'Should be greater than previous interval',
            });
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: The links change with time, please put what necessary from that page in your answer and remove the link

Answer (score 2):

To improve the performance of Alex's answer, use something like this to pre-calculate the lookup (using lodash).

```
yup.addMethod(yup.mixed, 'uniqueIn', function (array = [], message) {
    return this.test('uniqueIn', message, function (value) {
        const cacheKey = 'groups';
        if (!this.options.context[cacheKey]) {
            this.options.context[cacheKey] = _.groupBy(array, x => x);
        }
        const groups = this.options.context[cacheKey];
        return _.size(groups[value]) < 2;
    });
});
```

then call validate with an object for context so we can store our calculated group for the duration of the validate call

```
schema.validate(data, {context: {}}).then(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Improving on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74195685/15983164), this works for me

```
import { array, ArraySchema, Flags, number, object } from 'yup';

export const yupTestUnique = <
    TIn extends any[] | null | undefined,
    TContext,
    TDefault,
    TFlags extends Flags
>(params: {
    arraySchema: ArraySchema<TIn, TContext, TDefault, TFlags>;
    iteratee?: (
        value: TIn extends readonly (infer ElementType)[] ? ElementType : never
    ) => any;
    message?: string;
}) => {
    return params.arraySchema.test(
        "unique",
        params.message ? params.message : 'must be unique',
        (values, context) => {
            return values?.length
                ? new Set(
                    values.map((value) =>
                        typeof params.iteratee === "function"
                            ? params.iteratee(value)
                            : value
                    )
                ).size === values.length
                : true;
        }
    );
};

// Example
const createProductUnitValidationSchema = object({
    unitId: number().required(),
    price: number().required().min(0),
});

const createProductValidationSchema = object({
    productUnits: yupTestUnique({
        arraySchema: array()
            .required()
            .of(createProductUnitValidationSchema)
            .min(1),
        iteratee: (value) => value.unitId,
    }),
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).